# Install OpenCPU on a Bitnami server

Tags: ubuntu, bitnami, opencpu

Bitnami servers seem to use their own implementation of Apache, which runs independently of the standard Linux Apache. I'm not entirely sure how this works, but how do I 'tie' my OpenCPU install to the appropriate Apache implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to take the apache2 configuration files `/etc/apache2/sites-available/opencpu` and `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_r.load` and copy them to the other apache server.